# "apt upgrade" on aarch64 reports "No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host"

Tags: apt, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, 22.04

Every `apt upgrade` show this error/warning message

```
- Scanning processes...
Scanning candidates...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades.

Restarting services...
 systemctl restart udisks2.service

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

It seems `qemu` not installed on my system

```
# dpkg -l | grep -i qemu

# find / -name "*qemu*"
/usr/src/linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1008/tools/testing/selftests/rcutorture/bin/kvm-test-1-run-qemu.sh
/usr/src/linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1008/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/qemu
/usr/src/linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1008/include/uapi/linux/qemu_fw_cfg.h
/usr/src/linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1006/tools/testing/selftests/rcutorture/bin/kvm-test-1-run-qemu.sh
/usr/src/linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1006/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/qemu
/usr/src/linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1006/include/uapi/linux/qemu_fw_cfg.h
/usr/include/linux/qemu_fw_cfg.h
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/qemu
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/qemu-kvm
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/qemu-system-i386
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/qemu-system-x86_64
/usr/share/mime/application/x-qemu-disk.xml

uname -a
Linux swgrrege3 5.15.0-1008-raspi #8-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu May 19 11:58:51 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

How to solve / get rid of the warning:

> No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this
> host.

Answer (score 6):

This output comes from the invoked program `needrestart` and is just an information, as "No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host" basically translates to "All is up to date".

The check that returns "Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades" can not check the microcode of your CPU. It can be skipped by creating a new conf-file in `/etc/needrestart/conf.d/` with the content `$nrconf{ucodehints} = 0;`

If you want to get rid of the messages altogether then you can uninstall the package `needrestart`. But then processes will not be restarted automatically after their dependecies have been updated.

Comment: I wish to fix the warning, not just disable the messasge

Comment: When your processor can not be checked for microcode then you can only disable the check... And "No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host." translates to "All is up to date" - so no "warning" to fix... If you want to get rid of the messages altogether then you can uninstall the package `needrestart`.

Comment: thanks. Please edit/update your answer and I will upvote,